# Add a reference to an XSLT in Perl using only XML:LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I have a XML created dynamically. However, I want to add a reference to an XSLT file in it, to be able to render the XML file as HTML in Mozilla.

I want my final XML to start something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt_stylesheet_file.xsl"?>
<root_node>
</root_node>
```

I am not able to install XML::LibXSLT, so that is not a solution. 
Another solution would be to write the XML in a file, open it as a regular file and add the XSLT reference to it - but that just doesn't seem right to me.

Are there elegant solutions to this?

Edit:

Added some code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $final_xml = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0','utf-8');

 my $root_node = $final_xml->createElement('root'); 

 $final_xml->setDocumentElement( $root_node );


open (MYFILE, '>final.xml' );
 print MYFILE $final_xml->toString();
close (MYFILE);
```

And the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root/>
```

Comment: Can you show some of your Perl code?

Comment: I edited it and added code sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $final_xml = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0','utf-8');

my $pi = $final_xml->createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet");
$pi->setData(type=>'text/xsl', href=>'xslt_stylesheet_file.xsl');
$final_xml->appendChild($pi);

my $root_node = $final_xml->createElement('root'); 
$final_xml->setDocumentElement($root_node);

$final_xml->toFile("final.xml")
```

=>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xslt_stylesheet_file.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root/>
```

Comment: That's neat; I've never added processing instructions before. I would change the file writing though: `$final_xml->toFile("final.xml")` since it's there for you and does some error checking and encoding/decoding for you.

Comment: thx mzjin - this was exactly what I was looking for - thx a lot again - where or how did you found that `createProcessingInstruction`?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to generate XML, I'd use `XML::Writer`. then you can use the `xmlDecl` method to add your declaration. It's a more SAX-like API than `XML::LibXML`, but usually when generating documents that is not as much of an issue as when processing them. Also `XML::Writer` doesn't depend on the `libxml2` and `libxslt`, so it is much easier to install.