# Adding stylesheet to XML using Perl XML::LibXML on older system

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I'm trying to add a stylesheet directly into my XML generated by perl.

Using the information from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253965/add-a-reference-to-an-xslt-in-perl-using-only-xmllibxml#_=_) I was able to get it to work on my RHEL 6 system running perl v5.10.1.

However, when I run it on an older system, RHEL 5 with perl v5.8.8, my XML file only has this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet?>
```

Code used to generate XML

```
# Start XML Handling
use XML::LibXML;
my $XML = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');

# Add the lines for the stylesheet
my $xsl = $XML->createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet");
$xsl->setData(type => 'text/xsl', href => $CONFIG{'XML'}{'Stylesheet'});
$XML->appendChild($xsl);
```

Any ideas? I would like to do something cleaner than having my perl script modify the XMl as it's saving, but that's probably where I'm going to go next if I can't get this to work.

P.S. No, I cannot update the software on any system. :(

Comment: Are you running exactly the same file on both systems? What is the version of XML::LibXML installed on your RHEL5 system?

Comment: Yes, the exact same file. Just copied it to disk from my development workstation (RHEL 6) and put it on the RHEL 5 box this morning. I don't know what version of LibXML is installed... How do I see the version of a module?

Comment: `perl -MXML::LibXML -le 'print $XML::LibXML::VERSION'`

Comment: What result do you get from `print $xsl->toString, "\n"`

Comment: @choroba LibXML version 1.58 on the RHEL 5 system, version 1.7 on RHEL 6

Comment: @Borodin I get "<?xsl-stylesheet?>" on the 5 system. Is there a way to manually modify that and feed it back into $xsl so it has the correct attributes?

Comment: @MasterZ: And that's after the `setData` method call?

Comment: @Borodin Yes, it is.

Comment: @MasterZ: That's bizarre. Try adding a second call, something like `$xsl->setData( xxx => 'yyy' )` before the print. See if that makes any difference.  Also see what `$xsl->getData` returns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100712/discussion-between-masterz-and-borodin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means the ideal solution, but it works until someone can give me a better solution.

Part 1, check if the stylesheet string is blank.

```
if ( $xsl->toString eq "<?xml-stylesheet?>" ) { $CONFIG{'xslFixRequired'} = 1; }
```

Part 2, at the end of the script, right before saving the XML I search replace the string

```
my $FinalXML = $XML->toString($XMLFormat);

if ( $CONFIG{'xslFixRequired'} ) {
  $FinalXML =~ s/xml-stylesheet/xml-stylesheet type="text\/xsl" href="$CONFIG{'XML'}{'Stylesheet'}"/;
}
```